# Why TFDBatchMove raises exception ELocalTimeInvalid for date field with value "03/11/2019"?

Tags: json, delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.3 Rio Update 1 on a Windows 7 SP1 machine.

My program's purpose is to convert a `TFDMemtable` into a JSON format.   For a reason that I can't understand, when the date field of this `TFDMemTable` has the value `'03/11/2019'`, using the DisplayFormat `"day/month/year"`, it raises an exception:

> Project ProjMemtabJSON.exe raised exception class ELocalTimeInvalid with message 'The given "03/11/2019" local time is invalid (situated within the missing period prior to DST).'.

Any other dates different than `"Nov, 3rd 2019"` work fine.

I have no clue what is going on here!

```
program ProjMemtabJSON;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.JSON,
  FireDAC.Comp.DataSet,
  FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove,
  FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.DataSet,
  FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.JSON,
  Data.DB;

Var
  Fmemtable   : TFDmemtable ;
  FJSONArray  : TJSONArray;
  FDBatchMoveJSONWriter1     : TFDBatchMoveJSONWriter;
  FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1  : TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader;
  FDBatchMove1               : TFDBatchMove;

procedure  CreateMemtable;
begin
  Fmemtable := TFDmemtable.Create(nil);
  FMemTable.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger, 0, False);
  FMemTable.FieldDefs.Add('Name', ftString, 20, False);
  FMemTable.FieldDefs.Add('Status', ftString, 20, False);
  FMemTable.FieldDefs.Add('Duedate', ftdatetime,0, False);
  FMemTable.CreateDataSet;
end;

procedure FillMemtable;
begin
  FMemtable.Append;
  FMemtable.Fields[0].Value := 10;                           // ID
  FMemtable.Fields[1].Value := 'John';                       // Name
  FMemtable.Fields[2].Value := 'Active';                    // Status
  { ==> HERE IS THE PROBLEM :  change this date to 03/11/2019  i.e.  03/Nov/2019 and an error will raise }
  FMemtable.Fields[3].Value := StrToDate('02/11/2019');     // Due date dd/mm/yyyy
end;

procedure PrintMemtable;
begin
  writeln('ID       : ' ,Fmemtable.Fields[0].AsString);
  writeln('Name     : ' ,Fmemtable.Fields[1].AsString);
  writeln('Status   : ' ,Fmemtable.Fields[2].AsString);
  writeln('Due Date : ' ,Fmemtable.Fields[3].AsString);
end;

function TableToJson : TJSONArray;
begin
  Result := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1 := TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader.Create(nil);
    FDBatchMoveJSONWriter1    := TFDBatchMoveJSONWriter.Create(nil);
    FDBatchMove1              := TFDBatchMove.Create(nil);

    FDBatchMove1.Reader       := FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1 ;
    FDBatchMove1.Writer       := FDBatchMoveJSONWriter1;

    try
      if not FMemtable.Active then
        FMemtable.Active := True;
      FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1.DataSet := FMemtable;
      FDBatchMoveJSONWriter1.JsonArray  := Result;
      FDBatchMove1.Execute;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        raise Exception.Create('Error Message: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1.Free;
    FDBatchMoveJSONWriter1.Free;
    FDBatchMove1.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }

    Creatememtable;
    FillMemtable;
    PrintMemtable;

    FJSONArray   := TableToJSON;

    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, no matter how I set the short date format on my Windows 10 machine (`dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`) and no matter how I set the month and day (`03/11/2019` or `11/03/2019`).

Comment: What happens if you use EncodeDate instead of StrToDate? Also, why use the BatchMove process. The TFDMemDataset.SaveToFile can also save JSON files.

Comment: @Ken, thks.  I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows 7 SP 1.

Comment: @JacalarRick, I'm using BatchMove because I need to get a TJSONArray as Result   to be used as Body for a TRESTRequest POST method call !  I'll try EncodeDate and then let you know the result. Thks.

Comment: @JacalarRick, EncodeDate doesn't work as well.

Comment: *EncodeDate doesn't work as well* Are you sure? It appears that `StrToDate` isn't working at all - how could `EncodeDate` work less well than not at all? :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, I interpreted "as well" as "either".  In other words, fails the same way on the same date.  What is interesting is the full text of the error, which refers to Daylight Savings Time. Sunday, Nov 3, 2019 is the date, in the US, when DST ends (at 2am).  I wonder if that has something to do with the issue JRG is having.

Comment: The [`ELocalTimeInvalid` doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.ELocalTimeInvalid) says: "*The ELocalTimeInvalid exception is raised whenever a given local time is situated in an invalid period of time, usually when the hour shifts due to the DST (Daylight Savings Time) rules.*" Clearly something is trying to take the `TDateTime` stored in the MemTable and convert it to a UTC date/time that doesn't exist. `StrToDate()` and `EncodeDate()` don't do that, it has to be one of the `TFDBatchMove...` components. What does the stack trace look like when the error is raised?

Comment: Just curious, what happens if the field is defined as ftDate instead of ftDateTime?  Do you need/use the time portion?

Comment: @JacalarRick, you're right, I meant "either" above. Sorry for my poor English. One important information :  I'm using Windows 7 and my Region settings is set to Brazil GMT -3:00 . Last year the start date of Brazilian DST has changed.  As Ken said  he had no issue and n Windows 10,. I tried in Windows 2012 R2 and it worked fine.  I'm confused now !!  Thanks all.

Comment: Aha! That seems to be the issue. In the April 2018 DST update from Microsoft, the DST time change for Brazil is set at midnight on the 1st Sunday of November. Therefore, the datetime with a time portion=0 doesn’t exist (since midnight becomes 1:00am). Since you have declared the field as ftDateTime, set the time to 1200 (noon) for all your dates. Or, try declaring the field as just a ftDate and see if that works.

Comment: @JacalarRick, I changed the duedate field to ftDate , but the problem remains !

Comment: Was worth a shot. The exception is being raised due to the DST transition occurring at midnight (whole number datetime) versus some other hour. A small number of countries use midnight, rather than the more typical 1/2/3am; and Brazil is part of that group. Personally, I wouldn’t have coded the exception to be thrown for an exact midnight datetime, but the quickest way around this is to adjust the setting of your DueDate field to be `StrToDate()+0.5`

Answer (score 1):

There is a `System.DateUtils` routine that can check for an invalid time:

`TTimeZone.IsInvalidTime(const ADateTime : TDateTime) : Boolean;`

If you add `DateUtils` to your `Uses` clause, then update your FillMemTable to something like:

```
procedure FillMemtable;   
var  MyDate : tDateTime;
begin
  FMemtable.Append;
  FMemtable.Fields[0].Value := 10;                           // ID
  FMemtable.Fields[1].Value := 'John';                       // Name
  FMemtable.Fields[2].Value := 'Active';                    // Status
  { ==> HERE IS THE PROBLEM :  change this date to 03/11/2019  i.e.  03/Nov/2019 and     an error will raise }
  MyDate := StrToDate('03/11/2019');
  if TTimeZone.local.IsInvalidTime(MyDate) then MyDate := MyDate + 0.5; //noon won't be invalid
  FMemtable.Fields[3].Value := MyDate;     // Due date dd/mm/yyyy
end;
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, if you don't want the overhead of the IF statement, just force all dates to be noon.

I had never realized that there were time zones which switched to/from DST at midnight. Unfortunate, what with how Dates (without times) are defined.

Comment: thank you so much !  Very useful code.  I changed my code following your suggestions and it works now.  I hope to fix this definitively by aplying OS patch or upgrade.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: @jrg, if you could please accept my answer...  Of course, this is just a workaround for an underlying issue.  Even though there are certain dates in certain time zones where midnight falls in the Invalid Time period, I believe that an exact "0" for the time portion of a datetime value should never throw this exception: maybe the InvalidTime should start at time 00:00:00.01 to allow for the date without time.